# Find increase in OH- ion concentration after base is added

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, ph

> The pH of a solution is 7.00. To this solution sufficient base is added to increase the pH to 12.0. the increase $\ce{OH-}$ ion concentration is:
>
> (**A**) $5$ times
>   (**B**) $1000$ times
>   (**C**) $10^5$ times
>   (**D**) $4$ times

The answer is (**C**) $10^5$ times.

Now, the temperature hasn't been mentioned ergo we can't assume that it's a neutral soultion, right? So, I tried doing it this way:

\begin{array}{llll}
&\mathrm{pH} &= 7 &\qquad &\mathrm{pH} &= 12 \\
&[\ce{H+}] &= 10^{-7} &\qquad &[\ce{H+}] &= 10^{-12} \\
& & &[\ce{OH-}]~\text{added} \\
& & &= 10^{-7} - 10^{-12} \\
& & &= 10^{-7} (1 - 10^{-5}) \\
& & &\approx 10^{-7}
\end{array}

$[\ce{OH-}]$ added *is* the increase in its concentration, or so I think. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please, help.

Also, can you please point out the loopholes I might have in my concept if it's obvious from my doubt, so I can look up and take care of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to subtract the values, whereas all you need to do is find an increase in ratio $\frac{[\ce{OH-}]_2}{[\ce{OH-}]_1}$ knowing that $\mathrm{pOH} = - \log{[\ce{OH-}]}$ and $\mathrm{pOH} = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{w} - \mathrm{pH}$:

$$\frac{[\ce{OH-}]_2}{[\ce{OH-}]_1} = \frac{10^{-\mathrm{pOH_2}}}{10^{-\mathrm{pOH_1}}} = 10^{\mathrm{pOH_1} - \mathrm{pOH_2}} = 10^{\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{w} - \mathrm{pH_1} - \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{w} + \mathrm{pH_2}} = 10^{\mathrm{pH_2} - \mathrm{pH_1}} = 10^{12 - 7} = 10^5$$

Comment: pOH=14−pH is true only for 25°C. So,unless it's specified otherwise, are we to assume that the dissociation is taking place at 25C?

Comment: @JamilAhmed Yep, you are right, but considering the problem is not mentioning temperature at all, I assumed it's safe not to overthink and go for the easiest solution:)

Comment: how did you edit my question so perfectly?(if you get what i mean)

Comment: @JamilAhmed It's just basic MarkDown and MathJax, if you feel like you want to know a bit more, I'd suggest to read [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [How can I format math/chemistry expressions here?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: @JamilAhmed You only need to know that $\mathrm{pOH_1} + \mathrm{pH_1} = \mathrm{pOH_2} + \mathrm{pH_2}$, i.e. that the constant (the logarithm of the self-ionization constant) that is 14 at 25°C is the same before and after adding $\ce{OH-}$.

Comment: @wythagoras Good point, I changed $\mathrm{pOH} = 14 - \mathrm{pH}$ to $\mathrm{pOH} = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{w} - \mathrm{pH}$ in order to address the doubt about the temperature. Thank you!